# I cannot get an entry to register as a string. It keeps saying that it's a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

I was trying to make a menu and it gave me that error.

This is what the part that is the problem.

```
if self.Strawberry.get():
        stw = self.Strawberry_ent.get()
        stn = int(stw)
        stb = stn * 2.5
        total += stb
```

Comment: Without seeing more of your code there's no way to be sure, but it's pretty unusual to add strings generated from float objects together without any separators.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `total` is a string, you are missing a cast there:

```
total += str(stb)
```